# Does a polynomial $P(X,Y)$ that specializes to a polynomial $P(x_0,Y)$ with distinct roots in $\overline{k}$ have distincts roots in $\overline{k(X)}$

Tags: polynomials, fields, characteristic-p

Let $k$ be a field, $P\in k[X][Y]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$ in $Y$.

I am looking for a simple proof of the following fact.

"If there exists $x_0\in k$ such that $P(x_0,Y) \in k[Y]$ has (at least) two distinct roots in an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ then $P(X,Y)$ has (at least) two distinct roots in an algebraic closure $\overline{k(X)}$."

Intuitively, if there were a specialization map $\overline{k(X)} \to \overline{k}$, that would be obvious, but unfortunately I don't think this is the case.

So the idea would be to find an algebraic characterization of the polynomials that have only one root in an algebraic closure only in terms of its coefficients.
I kwow how to do it in characteristic zero (say writing down the condition implied by the fact that the image of the linear map $U,V\mapsto PU+P'V$ is "small"), but it does not work quite well in characteristic $p$, for we can have $P'=0$ for instance.

I feel that I maybe need more hypothesis on $k$ (probably perfect ?), although I have not been able to find any counter-example.

I am sure this should be well-known to someone here….

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if a specialisation of a polynomial has two distinct roots, then the original polynomial has two distinct roots, in the sense that you discuss.

Without loss of generality, $k$ is algebraically closed.

If $P(X, Y)$ does not have two distinct roots, then it is of the form $(Y - Q)^n$ for some $Q \in \overline{k(X)}$.

If $n \ne 0$ in $k$, then, since $n Q$ is the coefficient of $Y^{n - 1}$ in $P(X, Y) \in k[X, Y]$, we have that $Q$ belongs to $k[X]$.  Thus $P(x_0, Y) = (Y - Q(x_0))^n$ does not have two distinct roots, which is a contradiction.

Otherwise, $p \mathrel{:=} \operatorname{char}(k)$ is positive, $n$ is divisible by $p$, and so all terms in $P(X, Y) = (Y - Q)^n$ have $Y$-degree divisible by $p$.  Then $P_1(X^{1/p}, Y) \mathrel{:=} P(X, Y)^{1/p} \in k[X^{1/p}, Y]$ equals $(Y - Q)^{n/p}$, so, inductively, $P(x_0, Y)^{1/p} = P_1(x_0^{1/p}, Y)$ does not have two distinct roots, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure to understand so well. I am confused by the induction part. Is it an induction on the degree of $P$? But $P_1$ has the same degree as $P$, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I think that I understand. You're saying that $P_1(X^{1/p}, Y^{1/p})$ is in fact in $k[X^{1/p},Y]$ of degree $n/p$, correct?

Comment: @Oblomov, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464761/does-a-polynomial-px-y-that-specializes-to-a-polynomial-px-0-y-with-dist/464763#comment1207179_464763), no, I was actually just being careless, but that's what I *should* have been saying.  I have fixed it now; sorry for the carelessness!